# Playing video in EXOPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am using below code to play video using EXOPlayer but it doesn't plays.

Video is in `mp4` format.Where am I going wrong?
Its showing error-

```
com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: java.io.IOException: Failed to instantiate extractor.
```

Code-

```
loadvideo("res:/" + R.raw.samplevider);


private void loadvideo(String path) {
    player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(2, 1000, 5000);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    sampleSource = new FrameworkSampleSource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), uri, null);
    // 1. Instantiate the player.
    // 2. Construct renderers.
    videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
    audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource,MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT);
    // 3. Inject the renderers through prepare.
    player.prepare(videoRenderer, audioRenderer);
    // 4. Pass the surface to the video renderer.
    player.sendMessage(videoRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
    // 5. Start playback.
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        private static final int BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
        private static final int BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT = 256;
        private static final int RENDERER_COUNT = 3;

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(getAVideoUri());

        Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

        DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(this, null, getUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayerExample"));

        ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(
                    uri, dataSource, allocator, BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

        MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(
                    this, sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
        MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(
                    sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT);
        player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT);

        player.prepare(videoRenderer, audioRenderer, secondAudioRenderer);
        player.sendMessage(videoRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: It is not working either. The issue is related to the file encoding.

Comment: @LostPuppy Did you get a solution? Please help me get getDuration() for ExoPlayer and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777975/not-able-to-get-getduration-for-aac-file-using-exoplayer